# Node.Js var to html

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, powershell

I've stepped up a bit from just pure powershell..

I'm working with HTML, bootstrap, Javascript and Node.JS. I've only been doing this for a week so please be nice :D.

So I have a PS script writing data back to a SQL database, from there I was able to create a connection with the SQL database and pull the data with node. It should be stored in a var called myData. I will be doing data manipulation with javascript but my main problem is I can't get the var to show on my page... It just says undefined.

I bet I'm completely using node incorrectly, so any help you can give would be great! I am also a little confused on how the node.js is kicked off its not looking like hitting the node.js file in a browser is launching the connection. I have to open powershell or cmd and use  "node .\node.js". Does this file need to be a scheduled task to run and create the var on demand?

[image: capture]
[image: Site]

http://postimg.org/image/ar40onold/full

http://postimg.org/image/rswuqr3gh/full

```
    var sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
user: 'ECSM',
password: 'test',
server: 'epcatsql001', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
database: 'ECSM_Dash',
}

function getEmp() {
var conn = new sql.Connection(config);
var req = new sql.Request(conn);

conn.connect(function(err) {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
return;
}
req.query("select * from webBlobNP", function(err, data) {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
return;
} else {
console.log(data)
}
conn.close();
})
});

}
var myData = getEmp();
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href='css/main.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node.js"></script>
<head>
<title>Epic ECSM Dashboard</title>

</head>
    <div class='container'>
        <body>
        <p><script type="text/javascript">document.write(myData)</script></p>
        <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-12'>
        <h1>Epic ECSM Dashboard</h1></div>
        </div>
```

PS return

```
PS C:\Users\gordonc> node 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\node.js'
[ { collectedDate: '04/16/2016 14:44:34',
    serverName: 'sltenpblob002',
    reversion: 'IU 3',
    bVersion: '82.3.0',
    installDate: '4/4/2016',
    buildVersion: '2015' },
  { collectedDate: '04/16/2016 14:44:34',
    serverName: 'sltenpblob001',
    reversion: 'IU 3',
    bVersion: '82.3.0',
    installDate: '4/4/2016',
    buildVersion: '2015' } ]
PS C:\Users\gordonc> ^A
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how to ask questions. HONT: Show actual code instead of tiny picture of code

Comment: Yes, node is run from command line - normally on a server that can then be accessed from a browser but does not have to. You cannot load the html pages interacting with node from the file system using the file:/// protocol - at home you would likely use `http://localhost`

Comment: Sorry guys just noticed the pictures pure links attached. Im working on getting the code attached but I have a feeling im just not understanding the use of Node...

Comment: You are misunderstanding the asynchronous part of node.js. I think you should try a tutorial on how to query a db with node.js like https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/node-js-mysql first. Your code does asynchronous logs, but `myData` is in the wrong place.

Comment: Before any "complex" db tutorial, you should look into asynchronous javascript, it can be very confusing when not used to it. Here you go: http://nodeschool.io/#workshopper-list `javascripting` and `learnyounode` will give you a good general js/NodeJS basics. Also, NodeJS is server-side so in order to run it from your browser (a client), you'll need to run a server (`ExpressWorks` tutorial from nodeschool.io will do, it makes you work with ExpressJS, the most used web framework). Actually, a NodeJS file is just like a ps1 Powershell file, it only runs when you run it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help you guys. I was able to get my vard to save by moving it up into my else statement. so the undefined is gone but no data! lol....

thanks for the training ShanShan, Im working through codescool and freecodecamp for the javascript but the express and node will be very helpful! the training is running inside of a command window its really cool but odd at the same time.